# how can I display or return a instance of a django model by using another instance(which is primary key)

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-filter, django-model-field

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZMbL.png) I have `Wallet` class. with `fields` `user` and `Walletname`. When a new user is registered, a new Wallet object is created by signal. What I would like to do is display `Walletname`  of the current logged in user.

I tried filtering but I got error saying `%s is expected integer value`. However I have never created a instance named as id

Comment: Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: class Wallet(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Walletname=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)

Comment: sorry, I forgot to share the picture @SunderamDubey

Comment: I can get the current user as User.username and also the user in the Wallet class is same with User.username

Comment: You should edit the question with relevant code, it's not clear in comments.

Comment: Your question should contain the code relevant to the issue (in this case the class) in text format rather than a picture.

Comment: It's also added in the comments

Answer (score 0):

In your views try doing:

```
wallet = Wallet.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

then if you pass this to your front end you can display the name by doing:

```
{{wallet.Walletname}}
```

Comment: my view was class-based ı cant send request as parameters that's why ı tried to use User.username

Comment: TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>.  that's what I got. I used user=User

Comment: try using User.pk

Comment: nope didnt work

Comment: you need to add some code to your post I cant find out the solution if I cant see the problem

Comment: @DegerGökalp Can you also share your view by editing the question? Don't you know how to edit the question? You can click on edit button just below the question then post relevant code.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just uploaded my views, thanks